# Move resource to new site and use old url

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications, hosting

I have image Hosting 
i want to move image to new location and use old URL
it's possible ? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by changing the virtual path of your application.

Go through the following step for IIS 7 or 7.5

1. Create a folder with any name you like
2. Put your images there.
3. Go to IIS or run the `inetmgr`
4. Select your site from the list of sites under the ISS
5. Select the Basic Setting
6. change the physical path

**EDIT**

Create a website on your image server suppose it is http://www.imgServer.com 

Put you image in that website

And in you application use image url like http://www.imgServer.com/pathofthe image

Comment: Create a website over the image hosting site. and use it's url on the application server.